# Automating the action of downloading file and validating the status

Tags: java, automation, selenium-webdriver

My requirement, after cliking on the Export button, os save dialog appears where i need to select the download path and save it. Also i need to wait till the file download complete to make sure that the file is downloaded successfully.

I have used Selenium Webdriver till cliking on the Export button, I have handled the os save dialog for firefox browser by setting the firefox profile preferences to auto downlaod the file to the provided path. File starts downloading, but am stuck in verifying the status of file download. My file size varies and hence i cant wait for some time and check in the downlaod path, if the file exists. Also i will be not knowing the **file name** while exporting and **#href** attribute of Export button doesnot provide any url info.

can i use AutoIT? as am working on Windows platform.

I need to implement the above in IE, Chrome browsers as well. Pls let me know the possible solutions to handle the os save dialog and to verify the status of file download.

Comment: First read [How To Download Files With Selenium And Why You Shouldn’t](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: http://imobiliarerolabs.tumblr.com/post/64859016557/how-to-use-sikuli-when-automating-tests-with-selenium
It's Sikuli and can be used with Selenium.